# place input text value in two divs with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the autocomplete widget on my form which is basically providing a depart city text input field and a return text input field.

I would like to show in one div the Depart From, and Arrive At and in a second div the return information which would be the same. (i.e. Depart Toronto to Barrie and the Return, Barrie to Toronto).

My jQuery is working fine to display the information the first time but I can't get the information to show again reversed.

My form: (only displaying part)

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <p>
        <label for="tags">Depart From:</label>
        <input type="text" class="departCity" id="tags" size="30" />
    </p>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <p>
        <label for="tags2">To:</label>
        <input type="text" class="destination" id="tags2" size="30" />
    </p>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "_display").html($(this).val());
    });
});​
```

And html:

```
<div id="trip">
    <p><strong><span id="tags_display"></span> - <span id="tags2_display"></span></strong></p>
</div>
<div id="returnTrip">
    <p><strong><span id="displayTags2"></span></strong></p>
</div>
```

As I said, the first part in the "trip" div displays fine but I would like to clone/duplicate it in the second.

I tried this and some other variations but can't get it to display a second time. My form data is not going anywhere, it will only be displayed.

```
function open() {
    $('#displayTags2').html($('#tags2_display').clone());
}
open();​
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: when/on what event do you want to call the open() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to call the copying function that you have (what you have called `open()`).

You could create a button to add the trips to the list:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <p>
        <label for="tags">Depart From:</label>
        <input type="text" class="departCity" id="tags" size="30" />
    </p>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <p>
        <label for="tags2">To:</label>
        <input type="text" class="destination" id="tags2" size="30" />
    </p>
</div>

<div id="trip">
    <p><strong><span id="tags_display"></span> - <span id="tags2_display"></span></strong></p> 
</div>

<button class="copyTrip">Copy trip</button>

<div id="returnTrip">
    <p><strong><span id="displayTags2"></span></strong></p>
</div>
​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $('.copyTrip').on('click', function open() {
        $('#displayTags2').append($('#trip').clone());
    });

    $('input[type="text"]').on('change', function() {
        $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "_display").html($(this).val());
    });
});​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xkZtg/2/)**

**Edit 1**

So you just want to copy the destination value and put it in a hidden div? Easy.

I would copy the `$('#tags2').val()` each time it's changed, and just hide the `returnTrip` div unless your return trip checkbox is checked.

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type="text"]').on('change', function() {
        $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "_display").html($(this).val());
        $('#displayTags2').html($('#tags2').val());
    });

});​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xkZtg/3/)**

Comment: I really don't have to use the "open" here. The return portion of this form only shows if a return radio button is selected it is then that I would like to show the return information. The 'open' was just one of the possible solutions I explored while searching for a way to do this.

Comment: I've added an edit in reply to this. Sounds like you just want to copy the value and hide it. Yeah?

Comment: Perfect! Yes, that was exactly what I was trying to do and it now works. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

if i really understand your question, perhaps you mean something like this: call your `open()` function in your `blur()` method.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "_display").html($(this).val());
        //update immediately the Return city in the container
        open();
    });
});​
```